# MS Access reserved error (-2007) while importing Excel file

Tags: excel, ms-access

I'm trying to import an Excel table manually to MS Access and append it to a linked table there, which result in getting such an error message:

> Reserved error (-2007); there is no message for this error.

All columns of my Excel table correspond to the columns in the Access table and all the required fields are filled in. Moreover, when I create a local copy of the Access table and try to append my Excel file there, it works perfectly fine. 
Also, when I tried to append different Excel table to similar linked Access table, it worked as well, so there should be no problem with access rights.

Does anyone have any ideas, why doesn't it work this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the problem was with the one fields, which is supposed to be calculated automatically, and leaving it empty in the Excel table didn't allow for proper appending it to the Access table. 
The solution was just to delete this column in Excel file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your linked database corrupted. Try compact & repair both databases, if it won't help, create blank database, copy all objects from linked database and link to new database.

Comment: thank you for your recommendation! turned out the problem eventually was with only one field